# Wrapper to Interrupt a running program once a certain pattern is in output?

Tags: bash, shell, interrupt

Is there a way that I can wrap my program in a wrapper which will interrupt a given program once that program emits some pattern into the console.

Example:

```
wrapperBabySitterInterruptor programToRun 'StringToDetectToInterrupt'

someOtherCommandsToRun
```

Output

```
happy out out
some more happy output
StringToDetectToInterrupt
```

`wrapperBabySitterInterruptor` detects 'StringToDetectToInterrupt' and kicks in to interrupt `programToRun` Allowing `someOtherCommandsToRun` to run.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below functionality:

##script1.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "happy out out"
echo "some more happy output"
echo "StringToDetectToInterrupt"
echo "Should not be executed"
```

##script_wrapper.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
OIFS=$IFS;IFS=$'\n';for i in `bash script1.sh`;do echo $i;if [ $i == 'StringToDetectToInterrupt' ]; then break;fi;done
IFS=$OIFS
echo "someOtherCommandsToRun"
```

Explanation:

- `Script1.sh` is your main scripts which is printing some lines here
- `script_wrapper.sh` is the wrapper script, which is calling the main script and checking it's output.
- And, if main scripts prints `StringToDetectToInterrupt`, wrapper will `break` the for loop, killing the main script, and then continue to run other commands `someOtherCommandsToRun`
- Note: While running main script, I have changed `IFS` (internal field separator) variable to `newline` character, because for loop won't work properly with spaces, and once the for loop is finished, I am resetting it's value, which is stored in `OIFS` variable.